# Laravel file upload error return tmp file not exist

Tags: file-upload, laravel-4

I need to upload a csv file and process it on an import function.I have a code which is upload the file correctly ,soon after upload when I'm calling my import function its rturn an error `The file "/tmp/phpHYybvQ" does not exist`

Here my upload function

```
   public function postUpload ()
    {
    if (Input::hasFile('load_file')){

        $file = Input::file('load_file');
        $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

        //check out the edit content on bottom of my answer for details on $storage
        $storage = public_path();
        $path = $storage . '/lang';

        // Moves file to folder on server
        $upladed=  $file->move($path, $name);
        $langfile =  $upladed->getPathname();

        if ($langfile)
        return $this->import($path,$langfile);


    }
}
```

Here my form in the view file

```
 {{ Form::open(array('route'=>'languages-import','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true )) }}

    {{ Form::file('load_file','',array('id'=>'','class'=>'' ))   }}
    <input type="submit" value="Import Language CSV ">
    {{Form::token()}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

What is the problem with this error?

And I'm using a laravel artisan call in the import function.Here the artisan call

```
public function import($file){

    Artisan::call('lang:import',[$file]) ;
    return Redirect::back();

}
```

I'm using this package :https://packagist.org/packages/tlr/laravel-lang-tools

Comment: I bet you have form defined in bad way. Could you past here the form for file upload from view.

Comment: I added the form in the question